# How to make a python, command-line program autocomplete arbitrary things NOT interpreter

Tags: python, linux, unix, command-line, autocomplete

I am aware of how to setup autocompletion of python objects in the python interpreter (on unix).

- Google shows many hits for explanations on how to do this.
- Unfortunately, there are so many references to that it is difficult to find what I need to do, which is slightly different.

I need to know how to enable, tab/auto completion of arbitrary items in a command-line program written in python.

My specific use case is a command-line python program that needs to send emails.  I want to be able to autocomplete email addresses (I have the addresses on disk) when the user types part of it (and optionally presses the TAB key).

I do not need it to work on windows or mac, just linux.

Comment: This [blog](http://blog.e-shell.org/221) should do the tricks with config the .pythonrc file.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use Python's `readline` bindings.  For example,

```
import readline

def completer(text, state):
    options = [i for i in commands if i.startswith(text)]
    if state < len(options):
        return options[state]
    else:
        return None

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(completer)
```

The [official module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) aren't much more detailed, see [the readline docs](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC44) for more info.

Comment: note tough that if you write your command line with the cmd module that there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Note that readline doesn't work on Windows. pyreadline seems to be a drop in replacement though, but it doesn't work with linux.

Comment: You could just put a conditional at the start of your python file that checks the os and imports either `readline` or `pyreadline`.

Comment: @Samuel With `pyreadline` you use the same code snippet and just replace `readline` with `pyreadline`? Doesn't seem to work

Comment: On Windows 11: `AttributeError: module 'pyreadline' has no attribute 'parse_and_bind'`

Comment: Try readline = pyreadline.Readline(); readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete");.

Answer (score 65):

Follow the [cmd documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.cmdloop) and you'll be fine

```
import cmd

addresses = [
    'here@blubb.com',
    'foo@bar.com',
    'whatever@wherever.org',
]

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_send(self, line):
        pass

    def complete_send(self, text, line, start_index, end_index):
        if text:
            return [
                address for address in addresses
                if address.startswith(text)
            ]
        else:
            return addresses


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_cmd = MyCmd()
    my_cmd.cmdloop()
```

Output for tab -> tab -> send -> tab -> tab -> f -> tab

```
(Cmd)
help  send
(Cmd) send
foo@bar.com            here@blubb.com         whatever@wherever.org
(Cmd) send foo@bar.com
(Cmd)
```

Comment: Is there any way to control how readline columnizes it's output? So lets say i'd want it to columnize with two spaces between each item.

Comment: When I run this code, tabs are simply printed into the command line. In fact this is true regardless of if I use cmd or straight readline.

Comment: I see a lot of readline references in the cmd documentation. Does this work in a Windows shell?

Comment: @Hack Saw, I hit this problem on MacOS: the bundled `readline` isn't the same as what's on Linux, so I switched to Linux (a Raspberry Pi) and it worked immediately. There's something called `gnureadline` which might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 51):

Since you say "NOT interpreter" in your question, I guess you don't want answers involving python readline and suchlike. (***edit***: in hindsight, that's obviously not the case. Ho hum. I think this info is interesting anyway, so I'll leave it here.)

I think you might be after [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/317).

It's about adding shell-level completion to arbitrary commands, extending bash's own tab-completion.

In a nutshell, you'll create a file containing a shell-function that will generate possible completions, save it into `/etc/bash_completion.d/` and register it with the command `complete`. Here's a snippet from the linked page:

```
_foo() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="--help --verbose --version"

    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _foo foo
```

In this case, the typing `foo --[TAB]` will give you the values in the variable `opts`, i.e. `--help`, `--verbose` and `--version`. For your purposes, you'll essentially want to customise the values that are put into `opts`.

Do have a look at the example on the linked page, it's all pretty straightforward.

Comment: Actually i came here because of that

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 39):

I am surprised that nobody has mentioned [`argcomplete`](https://pypi.org/project/argcomplete/), available from PyPI. `argcomplete` doesn't provide generic autocompletion once your Python program is running, rather, it provides integration with your shell so that your shell can provide autocompletion for its command-line options. Here is an example from the docs:

```
from argcomplete.completers import ChoicesCompleter

parser.add_argument("--protocol", choices=('http', 'https', 'ssh', 'rsync', 'wss'))
parser.add_argument("--proto").completer=ChoicesCompleter(('http', 'https', 'ssh', 'rsync', 'wss'))
```

Comment: It's an old post, maybe argcomplete didn't exist back then? Thanks for mentioning it though, I think it's exactly what my project needs!

Comment: Very nice in combination with [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) as well!

Answer (score 16):

Here is a full-working version of the code that was very supplied by ephemient [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-int#187660) (thank you).

```
import readline

addrs = ['angela@domain.com', 'michael@domain.com', 'david@test.com']

def completer(text, state):
    options = [x for x in addrs if x.startswith(text)]
    try:
        return options[state]
    except IndexError:
        return None

readline.set_completer(completer)
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

while 1:
    a = raw_input("> ")
    print "You entered", a
```

Comment: Note that readline doesn't work on Windows, at least not in Python 2.7.18. pyreadline seems to be a mostly drop in replacement though, except you have to replace raw_input() with readline.readline(),

Answer (score 13):

```
# ~/.pythonrc
import rlcompleter, readline
readline.parse_and_bind('tab:complete')

# ~/.bashrc
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc
```

Comment: For mac os, replace ```readline.parse_and_bind('tab:complete')```
 with ```readline.parse_and_bind ("bind ^I rl_complete")```

Comment: This is Awesome. Worked for me. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Mani I was stuck in this for long time. Thank you so much

Answer (score 13):

You can try using the [Python Prompt Toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit), a library for building interactive command line applications in Python.

The library makes it easy to add interactive autocomplete functionality, allowing the user to use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to visually cycle through the available choices. The library is cross-platform (Linux, OS X, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Windows). Example:

[image: pgcli - Python Prompt Toolkit]

(Image source: [pcgli](https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli))

Answer (score 1):

The posted answers work fine but I have open sourced an autocomplete library that I wrote at work. We have been using it for a while in production and it is fast, stable and easy to use. It even has a demo mode so you can quickly test what you would get as you type words.

To install it, simply run: `pip install fast-autocomplete`

Here is an example:

```py
>>> from fast_autocomplete import AutoComplete
>>> words = {'book': {}, 'burrito': {}, 'pizza': {}, 'pasta':{}}
>>> autocomplete = AutoComplete(words=words)
>>> autocomplete.search(word='b', max_cost=3, size=3)
[['book'], ['burrito']]
>>> autocomplete.search(word='bu', max_cost=3, size=3)
[['burrito']]
>>> autocomplete.search(word='barrito', max_cost=3, size=3)  # mis-spelling
[['burrito']]
```

Checkout: https://github.com/seperman/fast-autocomplete for the source code.

And here is an explanation of how it works: http://zepworks.com/posts/you-autocomplete-me/

It deals with mis-spellings and optionally sorting by the weight of the word. (let's say `burrito` is more important than `book`, then you give `burrito` a higher "count" and it will show up first before `book` in the results.

Words is a dictionary and each word can have a context. For example the "count", how to display the word, some other context around the word etc. In this example words didn't have any context.

Comment: Does it work with both Windows and Linux shells?

Comment: @Samuel I have heard from people who are using it on Windows. The only thing that does not work on Windows is the interactive mode which is only meant for demo purposes.

Comment: Can you cause enter to be pressed (autocompleted) after verbatim keypresses to make keyboard shortcut bindings?

Answer (score 1):

This works well.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import readline
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

def complete(text,state):
    volcab = ['dog','cat','rabbit','bird','slug','snail']
    results = [x for x in volcab if x.startswith(text)] + [None]
    return results[state]

readline.set_completer(complete)

line = input('prompt> ')
```