# Python: Completer for path to dir/file

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm writing a CLI app and there is a place, where user should to write path to using dir. Of couse, I can read it with raw_input(), but standart Completer can't autocomplete path by TAB. So is there any solution in python (or somewhere else) or should I to write my own Completer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209484/howto-do-python-command-line-autocompletion-but-not-only-at-the-beginning-of-a-st), the [`readline`](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) module, and `readline.clear_history()` / `readline.add_history()`.

Comment: Yes, I can write function and make this with readline. But I hoped, that there is python module.

Whatever thank for the anwer.

Comment: @Ximik: chryss actually meant the python readline module [here](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html).

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad, I did indeed. Added the link to make it easier to spot.

Comment: @Muhammad Alkarour I understood, but default realization of Completer in this module doesn't support completion of the paths. In fact, this is my problem. But ok, seems like I have to write my own completer for readline.