# TAB autocomplete python CLI

Tags: python, shell, kde-plasma, tcsh

I was just wondering if it is possible to write a Python script that is run in the shell that can provide suggestions to the user when they hit Tab?

for example, how certain applications can limit the file types suggested by what they support.
I haven't found anything in optParse that does this?

Ideally it would be:

> myScript.py [TAB] 
>   (shell prints list of options)

Any suggestions? Specifically using KDE under OpenSuse and tcsh

Much appreciated

Comment: Have a look at the `cmd` module.  Specifically:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.completedefault

Comment: @KirkStrauser shows a way to do this with `readline` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/209503/190597).

Comment: It seems both those solutions require the python file to execute first? Is there a way I can do:
> myScript.py [TAB] 
 list of solutions

Thanks for the links though. Good to know about those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a feature of the shell, not of the Python script being called. See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570795/how-does-bash-tab-completion-work) for more info on shell completion. In particular, you're looking for [programmable completion](http://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?%28bash.info.gz%29Programmable%2520Completion).

Comment: Yup, I figured as much it might be but just wanted to check if it was possible to have it all inclusive.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like [optcomplete](http://furius.ca/optcomplete/). It implements a completion module for bash that will autocomplete the options for any Python program that uses `optparse`. You could take hints from that and convert it to what you need.

Comment: That indeed looks useful, as does compleat below. I'll try it at home where I have bash/zsh but work is strictly tcsh for the forseeable future. (Which is a pain because bash/zsh have such better communities)

Comment: Well, if tcsh has programmable completion, you might be able to adapt optcomplete do do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good explanation of how to do this for git. I'm including it inline, but credit goes to the [original author](http://gtirtha.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/git-autocomplete/)

```
# Source this script in tcsh to setup shell completions
# for git. Completions are activated by typing or Control-D
# in the shell after entering a partial command.
#
# Usage:
# source git-completion.tcsh (e.g. in ~/.cshrc)
#
# Supported completions:
# git (lists git commands)
# git help (lists git commands)
# git branch (lists branch names)
# git checkout (lists branch names)
# git log (lists the most commonly used flags)
# git remote (lists git remote commands)
# git remote add|prune|rm|show|update
# (lists git remote names)
# In addition to entering where shown, you can enter it after
# typing part of the word, e.g. git branch bug to auto-complete
# branches starting with “bug”.
#
# Author: David Adler, David Aguilar

if ( -x /usr/bin/git) then
# Git is installed so define tcsh completions for it.

# List of known git subcommands
# This is a hard-coded list to avoid calling ‘git help’ at startup.
set __git_cmd_names = (add bisect blame branch checkout clone commit config \
diff diff-files difftool fetch grep gui init log merge mv pull push \
rebase reset rm show shortlog stash status tag)

alias __git_aliases ‘git config –get-regexp “alias.*” | sed -n “s,alias\.\([^ ]*\).*,\1,p”‘
alias __git_branches ‘git for-each-ref –format=”%(refname)” refs/heads refs/remotes | sed -e s,refs/remotes/,, | sed -e s,refs/heads/,,’
alias __git_origin_branches ‘git for-each-ref –format=”%(refname)” refs/remotes/origin | grep -v HEAD | sed -e s,refs/remotes/origin/,,’

# Define the completions (see the tcsh man page).
complete git \
‘p/1/`__git_aliases | xargs echo $__git_cmd_names`/’ \
“n/help/($__git_cmd_names)/” \
‘n/branch/`__git_branches | xargs echo -m -d`/’ \
‘n/config/(–global –get-regexp –list)/’ \
‘n/diff/`__git_branches | xargs echo –check –staged –stat — *`/’ \
‘n/difftool/`__git_branches | xargs echo –no-prompt –staged — *`/’ \
‘n/fetch/`git remote`/’ \
‘n/merge/`__git_branches`/’ \
‘n/log/`__git_branches | xargs echo — –name-only –name-status –reverse –committer= –no-color –relative –ignore-space-change –ignore-space-at-eol –format=medium –format=full –format=fuller`/’ \
‘n/stash/(apply list save pop clear)/’ \
‘n/push/`git remote`/’ \
‘N/push/`__git_origin_branches`/’ \
‘n/pull/`git remote | xargs echo –rebase`/’ \
‘n/–rebase/`git remote`/’ \
‘N/–rebase/`__git_origin_branches`/’ \
‘N/pull/`__git_origin_branches`/’ \
‘n/rebase/`__git_branches | xargs echo –continue –abort –onto –skip –interactive`/’ \
‘N/rebase/`__git_branches`/’ \
‘n/remote/(show add rm prune update)/’ \
‘N/remote/`git remote`/’ \
‘n/checkout/`__git_branches | xargs echo -b –`/’ \
‘N/-b/`__git_branches`/’
endif
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a looksee and see if I can get it working for me.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[compleat](https://github.com/mbrubeck/compleat) enables tab-completion in bash using a simple usage description. `!command` syntax should allow to filter filenames dynamically.

Comment: I might try setting that up at home where I have access to zsh and bash. Work is strictly tcsh though and it looks like it's dependent on some bash underpinnings