# python double tabbing in cli to show compatible files only

Tags: python, linux, autocomplete

Please find the following snippet:

```
  import argparse

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      description="Create  plot from data",
      formatter_class=lambda prog: argparse.HelpFormatter(
          prog, max_help_position=27))
  action = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
  action.add_argument('--foo', help="Create foo plot")     # input is <filename>.foo
  action.add_argument('--bar', help="Create bar plot")     # Input is <filename>.bar
```

I run this in linux terminal emulator. Is it possible within python that, in the terminal, double tabiing will show only files with extension `foo` or `bar`, depending on argument, and not all the files in `PWD`?

I have found [TAB autocomplete python CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576488/tab-autocomplete-python-cli), but that is a decade old. Is there any option now?

**Update** @Lenormju:
I have updated the code as:

```
action.add_argument('--foo', help="Create foo plot", choices=('agr'))
  action.add_argument(
      '--bar', help="Create bar plot").completer = ChoicesCompleter('.agr')
```

So, now in terminal,

```
python ~/bin/code.py --foo [TAB][TAB]
```

I am expecting this to show files with `.agr` extensions only. Instead it is still shown all the files present in `PWD`.

Actually, this should not work, because "choices" means, I have to choose between 'a' 'g' or 'r'. May be I was not clear in the main question, show I have elaborated it.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to make a python, command-line program autocomplete arbitrary things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-int)

Comment: Old does not mean it is bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a python, command-line program autocomplete arbitrary things NOT interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-int)

Comment: No. I was probably not clear in the question. I want it while giving the cli, not auto complete in Python.

Comment: As for example, in linux, `evince [tab][tab]` only shows `pdf` files.

Answer (score 1):

When you press Tab, your shell expects to receive a list of strings (the possible completions).

- Either you register a Bash function to do the completion for your Python script (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/197158/11384184)) so that your Python script is **not** called until the command line is finished.
- Or else you do it with your Python script (see [this answer for `argcomplete`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23959790/11384184) which mixes well with `argparse`). In this case, Your Python script is indeed executed, but after computing the possible completions it will exit, and thus not run anything else. In other words, it will be called repeatedly to provide completion suggestions, then once at the end with the full command line to do its actual work.

Showing only the files with certain extensions depending on the argument is "just" a matter of customizing the completer.
Your question is really just a duplicate of [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/187621/11384184), but you seem to not see it. If the misunderstanding is actually on my side, please provide detailed explanations.