# python show only compatible files as cli

Tags: python, linux, command-line-arguments, gnome-terminal

This is a continuation of [python double tabbing in cli to show compatible files only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67818833/python-double-tabbing-in-cli-to-show-compatible-files-only). May be the question was not clear at the previous question.

The point is, in linux terminal emulator, with a pdf viewer, say evince, `evince [tab] [tab]` shows only `pdf` files as command line options. Similarly, an image viewer only shows image files. Can this be done from a python code? Or it is some property of the terminal (I guess it is about the viewer and mimetype).

Comment: If you're running bash, one way to achieve this (I suppose) is to bind a script/program/whatever to `TAB` in ~/.inputrc, e.g. I have "\C-v": "xclip -o^M" (^M is a literal Ctrl-M, i.e. Carriage Return).

Comment: Expect it to be slow.