# How can I implement incremental (find-as-you-type) search on command line?

Tags: scripting

I'd like to write small scripts which feature incremental search (find-as-you-type) on the command line.

Use case: I have my mobile phone connected via USB, Using gammu --sendsms TEXT I can write text messages. I have the phonebook as CSV, and want to search-as-i-type on that.

What's the easiest/best way to do it? It might be in bash/zsh/Perl/Python or any other scripting language.

Edit: 
Solution: Modifying [Term::Complete](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Complete) did what I want. See below for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Aiden Bell's hint, I tried Readline in Perl. 
Solution 1 using Term::Complete (also used by CPAN, I think):

```
use Term::Complete;   
my $F; 
open($F,"<","bin/phonebook.csv"); 
my @terms = <$F>; chomp(@terms); 
close($F);


my $input;
while (!defined $input) {
   $input = Complete("Enter a name or number: ",@terms);
   my ($name,$number) = split(/\t/,$input);
   print("Sending SMS to $name ($number).\n");
   system("sudo gammu --sendsms TEXT $number");
}
```

Press \ to complete, press Ctrl-D to see all possibilities.

Solution 2: Ctrl-D is one keystroke to much, so using standard Term::Readline allows completion and the display off possible completions using only \.

```
use Term::ReadLine;

my $F;
open($F,"<","bin/phonebook.csv");
my @terms = <$F>; chomp(@terms);
close($F);

my $term = new Term::ReadLine;
$term->Attribs->{completion_function} = sub { return @terms; };

my $prompt = "Enter name or number >> ";

my $OUT = $term->OUT || \*STDOUT;
while ( defined (my $input = $term->readline($prompt)) ) {
   my ($name,$number) = split(/\t/,$input);
   print("Sending SMS to $name ($number).\n");
   system("sudo gammu --sendsms TEXT $number");
}
```

This solution still needs a  for completion.

**Edit: Final Solution**
Modifying Term::Complete (http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/lib/Term/Complete.pm) does give me on the fly completion.

Source code: http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JE/JESSE/perl-5.12.0.tar.gz
Solution number 1 works with this modification. I will put the whole sample online somewhere else if this can be used by somebody

Modifications of Completion.pm (just reusing it's code for Control-D and \ for each character):

`170c172,189`

> ```
>         my $redo=0;
>
>                 @match = grep(/^\Q$return/, @cmp_lst);
>                 unless ($#match < 0) {
>                     $l = length($test = shift(@match));
>                     foreach $cmp (@match) {
>                         until (substr($cmp, 0, $l) eq substr($test, 0, $l)) {
>                             $l--;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     print("\a");
>                     print($test = substr($test, $r, $l - $r));
>                           $redo = $l - $r == 0;
>                           if ($redo) { print(join("\r\n", '', grep(/^\Q$return/, @cmp_lst)), "\r\n"); }
>                     $r = length($return .= $test);
>                 }
>                     if ($redo) { redo LOOP; } else { last CASE; }
> ```

Comment: I think you will hard pressed, unless you can hook on all keystrokes. These things need a trigger to call the complete procedure.

Answer (score 4):

I get the impression **[GNU Readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)** supports this kind of thing. Though, I have not used it myself. [Here is a C++ example](http://cc.byexamples.com/2008/06/16/gnu-readline-implement-custom-auto-complete/) of custom auto complete, which could easily be done in C too. There is also a [Python API](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) for readline.

**[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-inte) gives examples in Python**, one of which is ...

```
import readline
def completer(text, state):
    options = [x in addrs where x.startswith(text)]
    if state < options.length:
        return options[state]
    else
        return None
readline.set_completer(completer)
```

[this article](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) on Bash autocompletion may help. This article also gives examples of programming bash's auto complete feature.

Comment: It's an interesting idea to use the bash autocompletion feature. Even more I like the link to readline and ncurses (as I switch between zsh and bash at times). Thanks!

Comment: Standard readline requires <TAB> to be completed. I did not find a solution with readline yet which does not require <TAB> key (which searches on the fly).