# How to implement incremental search(vim like or man page like) in python

Tags: python, search, incremental-search

I have made a text box by python curse library, now I want to add incremental search function to it. In most linux software(like vim, man page), you are able to do incremental search by pressing '/'. Anybody have ideas how to do it in Python? I have been researching a while, but got no hints.
Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in urwid, instead. http://excess.org/urwid/

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2690309/1531136

Comment: Is the question how to do search at all? Or how to read individual keystrokes so you can make it incremental?

Comment: Yes I am asking how to the search. Actually I am using urwid and I have knew how to handle keystorke and display. @chkhan

Comment: @ymn, the readline module won't help, I already use ncurses terminal. and readline doesn't do search