# Is there a Python library for custom autocompletion?

Tags: python, parsing, user-interface, autocomplete, grammar

**Is there a *generic* library that would allow me to have autocompletion according to a *custom grammar and item list?***

Here's an example of what I am looking for.

Grammar:

- You can munch apples and mangoes
- You can drink milk and water
- You can move everything
- Sentence structure: verb [+ adjective] + object

Items:

- 1 green apple
- 1 microscopic apple
- 1 green mango
- 1 yellow mango
- 1 mango [no color given]
- 1 milk
- 1 water

Expected behaviour (user's input on the first line, suggestions on the second)

```
m
move, munch

mo
move

move g
move green apple, move green mango

move y
move yellow mango

move m
move milk, move mango, move microscopic apple
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a python, command-line program autocomplete arbitrary things NOT interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-inte)

Comment: @S.Lott - The question you are flagging as "exact duplicate" - while related - **it's not a duplicate**. That question only involves completing strings based on a list of other strings. My question is about defining grammar rules and then doing autocompletion based on that. :)

Comment: Please **update** your question to make it obvious how your question is different from the others which seem identical.  You might want to search for **all** the other Python autocompleter questions and identify specific differences from all the prior questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an acceptable solution by using a combination of [SPARK](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~aycock/spark/) (for grammar parsing / syntactic analysis) and my own code for autocompletion.

**About SPARK**

> SPARK stands for the Scanning, Parsing, and Rewriting Kit. It formerly
>   had no name, and was referred to as the "little language framework."
>   The first version (circa 1998) was described in the paper [Compiling
>   Little Languages in Python](http://www.python.org/workshops/1998-11/proceedings/papers/aycock-little/aycock-little.ps) at the 7th International Python Conference.
>
> SPARK is written in 100% pure Python, and is made available as open
>   source.

**The autocompletion code**

In the following code:

- `category` is the kind of word we are autocompleting. This is obtained by parsing the current command line. For example: if the user is typing *"drink m"*, the parser will know to expect a word in the category "liquids" defined in the grammar.
- The user input is stored in a list (`self.chars`)
- `_get_list_of_existing()` returns a list of existing words in a given category
- `_get_common_beginning()` return - if available - the longest initial supersequence for multiple matches. For example if the user input is writing *"ma"* and possible autocompletion words are *[magnolia, magnifying glass]* the `_get_common_beginning()` will return *"magn"*.

Here's the relevant code snippets:

```
def autocomplete(self, category):
    '''
    If possible, autocomplete a word according to its category.
    '''
    root = ''.join(self.chars).split()[-1]  #The bit after the last space
    pool = self._get_list_of_existing(category)
    matches = [i for i in pool if i.find(root) == 0]
    if len(matches) == 1:
        match = matches[0]+' '
    elif len(matches) > 1:
        match = self._get_common_beginning(matches)
    else:
        return
    self.chars.extend(list(match[len(root):]))

def _get_common_beginning(self, strings):
    '''
    Return the strings that is common to the beginning of each string in
    the strings list.
    '''
    result = []
    limit = min([len(s) for s in strings])
    for i in range(limit):
        chs = set([s[i] for s in strings])
        if len(chs) == 1:
            result.append(chs.pop())
        else:
            break
    return ''.join(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

One module for auto-completion I'm aware of is Qt's `QCompleter`, which you can use in Python via PyQt or PySide. I don't think it understands grammar in the way you mean, but it's generic enough to allow you writing code that does.