# Python Cmd module enabling tab-completion inside a double-quoted string

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, tab-completion

I'm currently writing an application using the Cmd/Cmd2 module.

For a certain command, I need quoted strings to delimit certain argument values.

```
(Cmd) command "This is an argument" argument 04
```

However, I can't seem to get tab-complete working with strings that start with a double quote. For example

```
command This<tab>
```

will autocomplete to

```
command This is an argument
```

However,

```
command "This<tab>
```

doesn't autocomplete to anything. Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround?

Thanks!

Edit: NVM, it does support quotes... it just seems that I had a bug elsewhere in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's some good information here: [How to make a python, command-line program autocomplete arbitrary things NOT interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-int)