# Get secondary input in Python to control history

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wanting to build a "input history" script within Python 2.x, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting a secondary input while using `raw_input()`, and writing to what the user inputs.

Because I found it a wee bit difficult to explain, I'm providing an example in JavaSript + HTML to try and clear things up.

### JavaScript + HTML Example

(In snippet form)

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input"),
  button = document.getElementById("button"),
  ihistory = document.getElementById("ihistory"),
  history = [],
  position = 0,
  text = "";

button.onclick = function() {
  if (input.value != "") {
    history.push(input.value);
    input.value = "";
    position++;
    input.focus();
  }
};

input.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 38 && position - 1 >= 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    position--;
    input.value = history[position].toString();
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40 && position + 1 <= history.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    position++;
    input.value = history[position].toString();
  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    button.click();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"></input>
<button id="button">Submit</button>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<hr />
<p>To Submit text to the text to the history, press "submit".</p>
<p>To access previous history, press the up arrow key. To access future history, press the down arrow key.</p>
```

I'm not sure it is possible to write to what the user inputs, so that they can edit it, etc, without writing C/++ code. I'm fine with it if it does require C/++, or if it requires any weird (but preferably small) modules.
Also, I'm progamming this in a Linux environment, so I am not interested it Windows/Mac-only answers.

Comment: Anything I can do to make my intentions clearer, I apologise for not doing in the first place. Tired-programming is never fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is readline functionality.  There are some samples of how to use it [here](https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/tag/readline/).  Once you've got your head around the function, you'll probably find that this is already answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-int).

Comment: Can't believe I didn't find that post, or that module... Nevertheless, I am now less-of-a-newb.