# Python - Filter a list with an interactive CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, command-line-interface, prompt

we are trying to build an interactive CLI with Python 3.

We should ask some questions to the user, at the moment we are using this library: https://github.com/CITGuru/PyInquirer

We are using the type *list* to print the list of the choiches, but this can be quite annoying when the list is very long.

Do you have any clue about how we can implement a filter on the list as the user is typing? Something very similar to the autocomplete library for Javascript.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-int

Comment: see [Python Prompt Toolkit 3.0](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Answer (score 0):

One tool that I personally like a lot is the **Click** lib.

Here's the documentation part that talks about autocomplete:

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/bashcomplete/

I hope it works the way you want it to.